# Syntax: Function to return parameter of a discriminated union in F#? (Pattern match on function parameter)

Tags: f#

I'm obviously a newbie to F#. Comming from C#, I'm having difficulty with Discriminated Unions.

Assuming the following definitions in F#:

```
type Details =
            | ContactDetails of ContactDetail * id: Guid
            | Internet       of Internet  * id: Guid    
            | PhoneNumbers   of PhoneNumber  * id: Guid 
            | Addresses      of Address     * id: Guid  
    
        let contactDetail  : ContactDetail = {Name="Contact Detail"; Content="Content for Contact Detail"; Text="here is the contact detail text" }    
        let internet       : Internet = {Name="Internet";       Content="Content for Internet";       Text="here is the internet text" }
        let phoneNumber    : PhoneNumber =  {Name="Phone Number";   Content="Content for phone number";   Text="here is the phone number text" }
        let address        : Address = {Name="Address";        Content="Content for Address";        Text="here is the Address text" }
       
        let details   = [ContactDetails (contactDetail,Guid.NewGuid())
                         Internet       (internet,Guid.NewGuid())
                         PhoneNumbers   (phoneNumber,Guid.NewGuid())
                         Addresses      (address,Guid.NewGuid())
                         ]


type Model = {
      Details: Details list
    }
```

How do I write the function that takes in the Model and returns the id of each item in the list?

i.e., something like:

fun detail -> detail.id

***The type 'Details' does not define the field, constructor or member 'id'***

TIA

Edit#1:

New Model is:

type Model = {
Details: DetailsWithId list
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Discriminated" in Discriminated Union means that each field definition is considered distinct from the other, which is why, even though you have a common field, it is not accessible directly.

The simplest thing that I usually do is create an extension function that safely extracts that field.

```
type Details =
            | ContactDetails of ContactDetail * id: Guid
            | Internet       of Internet  * id: Guid    
            | PhoneNumbers   of PhoneNumber  * id: Guid 
            | Addresses      of Address     * id: Guid  

    member this.id = 
        match this with
        | ContactDetail(_, id)
        | Internet(_, id)
        | PhoneNumber(_, id)
        | Address(_, id) -> id
```

Another option is to construct your data differently:

```
type Details =
     | ContactDetails of ContactDetail
     | Internet       of Internet
     | PhoneNumbers   of PhoneNumber
     | Addresses      of Address

// Each instance will hold one of ContactDetails, Internet, Phonenumber, and
// each has a common property of ID (the Guid). This way, you simplify your model
type DetailsWithId = DetailsWithId of Details * Guid
```

One other remark: you use plural form for each member of the DU, but the definition allows only one item.

Comment: The second method is really what I was trying for, but could not get it right. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show how DetailsWithId is initialized? I'm getting nowhere fast.

Comment: @AlanWayne, if you have a `Details` instance, let's call it `dtl`, and a `Guid`, let's call it `id`, you can created an instance of `DetailsWithId` by using normal tuple syntax: `let dtlWithId = DetailsWithId(dtl, id)`.